# Preciso executar um Select no C# porém não encontro a Connection String nem a variável connection

Tags: c#, sql-server

Gerei toda a parte do banco de Dados com o visual Studio e agora preciso fazer um *Select* com o método SqlCommand() para um sistema de Login no banco de dados porém preciso encontrar a o nome da variável conexão com o banco para executar o comando, procurei no próprio site da microsoft e descobri que tem uma Connection string que tem o seguinte método

`static private string GetConnectionString() { return "Data Source=sqlserver;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;" + "Integrated Security=true;"; } }`
porém não consigo conectar pois não encontro o Campo Data Source, não consigo encontrar a variável da conexão com o banco de dados nem essa String.

Alguém sabe onde encontro essa variável connection ou o nome do Data Source?

já pesquisei em diversos locais porém eles ensinam a criar a conexão com o banco do zero e eu não quero recriar tudo do começo

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: O que você quer dizer "encontrar a variável"?

Comment: Preciso Encontrar a Instância que está em negrito, do método abaixo, porém não consigo encontrar

private static void OpenSqlConnection()
{
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

    using (SqlConnection **connection** = new SqlConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

        connection.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
        Console.WriteLine("ConnectionString: {0}",
            connection.ConnectionString);
    }
}

Comment: Seu comentário não faz muito sentido pra mim. Como você pretende "encontrar" uma instância? Instância você cria...

Comment: então esse é o problema o código criou a conexão com o banco de dados e eu preciso utilizar a instância que foi criada para executar o comando SqlCommand, ou será que eu preciso instanciar uma nova conexão?

Comment: Você precisa criar uma connection string para o seu banco de dados